# How to Update Textbox.Text on Button Press

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, textbox

Apologies for what is undoubtedly a newb question, but I have been unable to find a specific answer.

I have c#-integrated ASP.net Core project, with an SQL backend. I can run queries for individual entries just fine, but my problem is a far more mundane one.

I have a textbox, which I want to reload the page when the Enter key is pressed which the Text value appended to it. E.g. '~/GetPerson?name=' with the text the user's entered placed at the end.

This seems simple enough, and I'm probably missing the obvious, but I remain befuddled.

Comment: How about wrapping the input field in a form which has method="GET" ? When you submit the form (try hitting enter after entering some input) the value will be appended in the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

do you want this?

```
$("#textBox").on("keyup", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.keyCode===13){
       //do call server or something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$("#textBox").on("keyup", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.keyCode===13){
       var name = (this).val();
       window.location.href = '@Url.Action("GetPerson", "YourController")?name=' + name;
    }
}
```